# How to recover a list sent by a javascript function called through cefSharp in my c# program after a page has loaded?

Tags: javascript, c#, multilingual, cefsharp, eventhandler

I'm writting a c# program using cefSharp which uses the data present on a webpage. My problem comes when retrieving the information I need form the webpage. I nedd to get that information as a list.

I first tried simply waiting for the entire page to have fully loaded however this is way too long given the fact that I only need the DOM to be loaded and that retrieving the list should be carried efficently. I was advised to use an eventHandler to be able to call the javascript method returning the list exactly when the DOM is done loading. My problem is that an eventHandler can't return any value so even though I can call my method at the right time, I can't get the value it returns in my c# program. I dont know what to do. Is there a way to call my method at the right time and still get the value it returns?

Here is the code i have tried :

```
browserStartedLoading = async (sender, args) =>
{
   browser.EvaluateScriptAsync("window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', 
   function() { ... });").ContinueWith(x =>
   {
                            var response = x.Result;
                            if (response.Success && response.Result != null)
                            {
                                list = (List<object>)response.Result;

                            }
   });
}
```

Comment: What makes you think DOM loaded and say LoadingStateChange are that different in their execution time?  What you are attempting would require you to bind an object.

Comment: See https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/General-Usage#3-how-do-you-expose-a-net-class-to-javascript